# Normalization of multiple similar tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

i'm quite new to all this tech stuff so excuse me for making mistakes - beforehand.

My question is regarding data normalization. I'm using PGadmin4 for this task.

I have multiple tables one for each year containing multiple columns. I wish to normalize these data in order to make further inquiries. The data is in this form:

```
Table 1 
| id | name1 | code1| code2 | year|
| 1  | Peter | 111  | 222   | 2007|

Table 2
| id | name1 | code1| code2 | year|
| 2  | Peter | 111  | 223   | 2008|
```

So my tables area similar but with some different data each year

I have broken it down so i have multiple tables containing  only one column of information:

```
name1_table
| id | name1 |
```

And i have done this by every column. Now i need to link it all together - am heading in the right direction or have i gone of in a bad one?

What is the next step and if possible what is the code i need to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to combine two tables with identical schemas is to create a new third table with the same schema and copy all the records into it.

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table3 SELECT * FROM Table1;
INSERT INTO Table3 SELECT * FROM Table2;
```

Or if you simply need a combined query result you can use UNION:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table2;
```

Comment: so what you suggest is to make one large table with all data from each year, and normalize from there? - This might actually make things easier. Thank you for helping me think a little out of the box.

Comment: `SELECT`ing all data into one big table will help you see which columns have common data that you can abstract off into their own table. I'd recommend going with the `UNION` method, since that will make sure that both of your tables have the same order of columns. Plus, the `UNION` will get rid of dupes. If you are 100% certain that the tables won't contain dupes, you can use `UNION ALL` to make it a lot faster.

Comment: I would definitely go with ha single table. Then if you want only records for one year you can add a 'WHERE Year = 2008'

Answer (score 0):

You are *not* headed in the right direction.  The best approach is simply to store all the data in one table and to use indexes and/or partitions to access particular rows.

Sometimes this is not possible, notably because the tables have different formats.  Possible solutions:

- Break the existing tables into similarity sets based on columns, and create one table for each similarity set.
- Create a table based on the *most recent* definition of the table, `NULL`ing out columns that don't exist in historical tables.
- Use a facility such as JSON for columns that have changed over time.
- Use a facility such as inheritance for columns that have changed over time.